# How to use awswrangler to write a pyarrow table to parquet to prevent Out of Bounds error on dates

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a dataframe with dates that have a future date ie. 9999-12-31, and these are out of bounds for any pandas datetime type. My goal is to write these to an S3 bucket in parquet format, where the table schema is pre-defined as 'timestamp'.

Currently when using `awswrangler.s3.to_parquet¶` the file is written with the date columns as string - this results in this error when querying the result in Athena:

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field [date_col]'s type BINARY in parquet file s3://... is incompatible with type timestamp defined in table schema

Is there a way to cast this date col to a date type that supports out of bounds date, such as Pyarrow's pa.Timestamp('s) type?

Alternatively, is there a way to write Pyarrow tables, instead of Dataframes, when using `awswrangler.s3.to_parquet¶`? This will enable me to create a Pyarrow table with the correct schema that matches that in AWS Glue.

I've tried using the dtypes argument in `awswrangler.s3.to_parquet¶` to set the date col as a  Glue timestamp type: `dtype={'date_col':'timestamp'}`, but this gives the out of bounds error.